# Can't use openssl server because the ciphers are outdated...or something...ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH

Tags: c++, openssl

This question is a bit easier than my last one so hopefully I'll get literally any response like at least a comment (please.)

I am trying to create a simple tls socket server using OpenSSL, but can't complete a handshake because my server doesn't have any ciphers that any browser will use (that's what I deduce.) Chrome says "`ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH`" and Firefox says "`SSL_ERROR_NO_CYPHER_OVERLAP`." The program itself keeps running.

It's a pretty simple program, so I am not sure why it fails this way. The version of openssl installed on my machine is `1.1.0l-1~deb9u1`, but I'm not sure if that's what the compiler actually links when I use `-lcrypto` or how I would determine that.

```
int main() {
    SSL_library_init();

    OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms();
    OpenSSL_add_all_ciphers();
    SSL_load_error_strings();
    SSL_CTX* ctx = SSL_CTX_new(TLSv1_2_server_method());

    SSL_CTX_use_certificate_file(ctx, "example-com.cert.pem", SSL_FILETYPE_PEM);
    SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey_file(ctx, "example-com.key.pem", SSL_FILETYPE_PEM);

    int sd = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    struct sockaddr_in addr;
    addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    addr.sin_port = htons(8080);
    addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    bind(sd, (struct sockaddr*) & addr, sizeof(addr));
    listen(sd, 100);
    while (1) {
        struct sockaddr_in clientAddr;
        socklen_t len = sizeof(clientAddr);

        SSL* ssl = SSL_new(ctx);
        int clientFD = accept(sd, NULL, NULL);
        SSL_set_fd(ssl, clientFD);
        SSL_accept(ssl);
        char buf[1024];
        int bytes = SSL_read(ssl, buf, sizeof(buf));
        std::string reply = "HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently\r\nCache-Control: no-store\r\nLocation: https://google.com/ ";
        SSL_write(ssl, reply.c_str(), reply.length());
        SSL_free(ssl);
        close(clientFD);
    }
    close(sd);
    SSL_CTX_free(ctx);
    return 0;
}
```

edit: According to the man page, `TLS_server_method()` should be used, but that yielded the same result. I also tried using `SSL_CTX_set_options()` and `SSL_CTX_set_cipher_list()` but with same results.

Comment: Don't you need to include some headers as well? Btw, I get `const SSL_METHOD* TLSv1_2_server_method() is deprecated`.

Comment: Why is it deprecated? I thought TLS 1.2 is still widely used? What is generally recommended instead?

Comment: Yes, it is, but apparently the function `TLSv1_2_server_method()` is deprecated. I don't know more than that.

Comment: @TedLyngmo According to the man page, `TLS_server_method()` should be used, but that yielded the same result. I also tried using `SSL_CTX_set_options()` and `SSL_CTX_set_cipher_list()` but with same results.

Comment: I see. This is not something I know much about. Are your certificates up to date? Perhaps you need to generate or acquire new certs?

Comment: @TedLyngmo That's a good question. I just generated these. I've tried following a few different tutorials. One that I tried was the [Let's Encrypt localhost](https://letsencrypt.org/docs/certificates-for-localhost/) page. Maybe it's possible these certificates don't generate in "pem" format, but I don't even know what that is. OpenSSL could just be trying to use them even though they're useless.

Comment: Wireshark shows the client hello, then the server just sends an Alert

Comment: Hmm ... I use Let's Encrypt's certs for my own webpage and they always seem to work. It was years ago I did it though. I know you can run `openssl` to show the time period for which a cert is valid, but I as I said, it was too long ago.

Comment: @TedLyngmo I figured out one of my issues. The binary did not end up in the same folder as the source, so the certificate and pk were not actually being used. I simply pointed it to the exact directory. If you want you can get those answer points for helping me. How do I add headers?

Comment: Great! I mean the normal `#include <openssl/...>` headers and the `c++` headers you need to be able to compile the program. They are not included in the question, but needed for someone trying to help.

Comment: Oh I thought you meant some sort of HTTP response headers. Yes, I just cut off the includes to save space. Ironically chrome now tells me ERR_RESPONSE_HEADERS_TRUNCATED

Comment: "_I just cut off the includes to save space_" - Don't :-) That tiny bit of saved space makes people jump to the next question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, to clean a bit up, instead of:

```
SSL_CTX* ctx = SSL_CTX_new(TLSv1_2_server_method());
```

you may try:

```
const SSL_METHOD *method;
method = SSLv23_server_method();    /* negotiate the highest protocol version supported by both the server and the client */

M_ssl_ctx = SSL_CTX_new(method);    /* create new context from method */

if ( M_ssl_ctx == NULL )
{
    // error message
    return -1;
}
```

`SSLv23_server_method()` ensures compatibility with older OpenSSL versions and now is simply a macro replacing it with `TLS_server_method()`.

Then (before certificates) you may need to add:

```
if ( SSL_CTX_set_ecdh_auto(M_ssl_ctx, 1) <= 0 )
{
    // error message
    return -1;
}
```

Older SSL versions required this to support elliptic curves algorithms.